# Why do we need to return the head pointer in a BST after inserting node?

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search-tree

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct BTreeNode BTNode;
struct BTreeNode
{
int value;
struct BTreeNode *left_child,*right_child;
};

BTNode* insert(int input_value, BTNode **head_node)
{
    BTNode *temp,*head;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(BTNode));
    temp->value = input_value;
    temp->left_child = NULL;
    temp->right_child = NULL;
    head = *head_node;
    while(1)
    {
        if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;
//          break;
            return head;
        }
        if(temp->value > head->value)
        {
            if(head->right_child == NULL)
            {
                head->right_child=temp;
            }
            else
                head = head->right_child;
        }
        else if(temp->value < head->value)
        {
            if(head->left_child == NULL)
            {
                head->left_child=temp;
            }
            else
                head = head->left_child;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return *head_node;
}

int insert_wor(int input_value, BTNode **head_node)
{
    BTNode *temp,*head;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(BTNode));
    temp->value = input_value;
    temp->left_child = NULL;
    temp->right_child = NULL;
    head = *head_node;
    while(1)
    {
        if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;
//          break;
            return 1;
        }
        if(temp->value > head->value)
        {
            if(head->right_child == NULL)
            {
                head->right_child=temp;
            }
            else
                head = head->right_child;
        }
        else if(temp->value < head->value)
        {
            if(head->left_child == NULL)
            {
                head->left_child=temp;
            }
            else
                head = head->left_child;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void printtree(BTNode **head_node)
{
    BTNode *head;
    head = *head_node;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
//      printf("Print exit\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d\n",head->value);
        printtree(&(head->left_child));
        printtree(&(head->right_child));
    }
}

int main()
{
    BTNode *root=NULL,*root_wor=NULL;
    root=insert(23,&root);
    root=insert(32,&root);
    root=insert(230,&root);
    root=insert(3,&root);
    root=insert(2,&root);
    root=insert(50,&root);
    printtree(&root);
    insert_wor(24,&root_wor);
    insert_wor(42,&root_wor);
    insert_wor(45,&root_wor);
    insert_wor(12,&root_wor);
    insert_wor(87,&root_wor);
    insert_wor(123,&root_wor);
    printtree(&root_wor);
}
```

In the above code I have written two different functions to insert node in a BST.
1)In one function I am returning the head pointer after inserting a node in it.
2)In the second function I am not returning the head pointer.
when I am trying to print the BST first one is working fine but I am not able to print
second BST.
My doubt is as per the concept of pointers even though we make changes in the member function it should reflect in the main function, but in this case(In the second method when I am passing head and making changes to it in member function they are not reflecting in main function) that is not happening??
I think I am getting confused at some point. Could anyone please help out in clarifying this??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second version, `head = *head_node;` **copies** the head pointer. When you change `head` later on, the original pointer (pointed to by `head_node`) won't ever get updated. If you always used `*head_node` instead of a copy of it, or if you assigned `*head_node = head;` before returning, then the `insert_wor()` function would work as well.

Comment: But when we assign *head_node to head and update head then *head_node should also be updated know ??

Comment: I think assigning *head_node to head copies the address of root as I am passing &root to **head_node

Comment: @user1317234 And then what? You need the copying in the opposite direction as well.