# Why no element gets inserted in my BST

Tags: c, binary-tree

Here i am trying to implement a binary search tree.I declared root node in global context.I followed the same idea how i implemented linked list.But this approach doesn't seem like working.I can't figure what is wrong in this code.Can anyone help me figure this out

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct node {

    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};
void insert(int value);
void push(struct node *temp,struct node *newNode);


struct node *root;
int main(){
    root= NULL;
    int option,value;
    for(;;){
       printf("Please select an option from below : \n");
       printf("1 for insert\n");
       printf("2 for search\n");
       printf("please enter your option : ");
       scanf("%d",&option);
       printf("\n");
       switch(option){
           case 1:
               printf("you choose to insert\n");
               printf("input your value :");
               scanf("%d",&value);
               insert(value);
               printf("\n");
               break;
           case 2:
               printf("You choose to search\n");
               printf("enter your value : ");
               scanf("%d",&value);
               search(root,value);
               printf("\n");
           default:
               break;

       }
    }
}

void insert(int value){
    struct node *newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    newNode->data = value;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;


    push(root,newNode);

}
void push(struct node *root_node,struct node *newNode){

  if(root_node==NULL){
         root_node = newNode;
         printf("inserted\n\n\n");
    }else{
         if(root_node->data > newNode->data){
              push(root_node->left,newNode);
              printf("left\n");
         }else{
            push(root_node->right,newNode);
            printf("right\n");
         }

    }

}
```

Comment: In `push()`, `root_node = newNode;` serves no purpose as it does not affect the calling code.  Many dupes on this one.  Perhaps [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172603/why-do-we-need-to-return-the-head-pointer-in-a-bst-after-inserting-node)?

Comment: can u please explain a bit..i am still confused!

Comment: Search for and read about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: Code assigns `root_node` with `root_node = newNode;` and then does nothing with that assignment.  It serves no purpose.  What did you expect that assignment to do?

Comment: initially it will craete a new node as root node...after that it will recursively add nodes to tree

Comment: You must understand first why your solution is wrong. You are misunderstanding pointers. A pointer is a variable who's value is an address. Take a look at my answer, and then review pointer's theory :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `push()`, root_node is a **local variable**:

```
void push(struct node *root_node,struct node *newNode){
```

When you do:

```
root_node = newNode;
```

you are only updating the local variable "root_node", not the global:

```
struct node *root;
```

Your push() should be something like:

```
void push(struct node **root_node,struct node *newNode){
    if(*root_node==NULL){
        *root_node = newNode;
        printf("inserted\n\n\n");
    }else{
...
```

and call:

```
push(&root, newNode);
```

In this way, you pass the address of root, and inside you check if the pointed by that address is NULL. If it is null, you assign the address of newNode into the pointer [dereferenced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator).

More explanations:

`struct node *root` is a pointer: a variable who's type is "pointer/address". And points to a block in memory of data, let's call "A".

`struct node *root_node` is a pointer, as local variable, it is a **COPY**, that points to a block in memory of data, and in your case (since you pass "root") points to "A".

When you modify `root_node`, your **copy** does not modify `root`. What you are doing can only be used to modify "A".

You have to pass the ***address*** of root, so you can actually modify root's value, which is a pointer to "A". In that way, you have **root_node which is a pointer to `root`, ACTUAL `root`, which points to "A", and you can make it point to other place (as you want).

I upload an image to show why your solution is wrong:

[image]

As you can see, `root` is **never** updated.

(P.S.: You can read "copy the pointer" as "copy the variable", since a pointer is a variable who's value is an address. And you dereference the address with `*variable`).

Comment: in your push function if(*root_node==NULL) here... *root_node means the address of &root....isn't it? so address can't be null..so how i am supposed to insert the first node?

Comment: No, `root_node` is `&root` (the address of root), and then `*root_node` is `root`. Did you read the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator ? Here is graphically the dereference: http://images.slideplayer.com/19/5772771/slides/slide_38.jpg . Let's try this to understand it: Draw me where are your variables, the heap and the stack once you are inside my push() and what is each one, where does it points, etc. :)

Comment: I forgot to comment. In my push() function, you can do `(*(*root_node)).data` to access the data of a node :). Remember the syntactic sugar tip that `(*variable).field` can be written as `variable->field`, so you can write `(*(*root_node)).data` as `(*root_node)->data`

Answer (score 0):

The following lines are **NOT** updating the global variable `root`.

```
    push(root,newNode);

}
void push(struct node *root_node,struct node *newNode){

  if(root_node==NULL){
         root_node = newNode;
         printf("inserted\n\n\n");
```

Since you want `root` to be global, one option is to change this in the following way so that the global `root` is used.

```
    push(newNode);

}
void push(struct node *newNode){

  if(root == NULL){
         root = newNode;
         printf("inserted\n\n\n");
```

and so on. (Note: this is not a complete solution.)

Comment: struct node *root_node is a pointer to root node itself.So why it should not update it ?

Comment: in your second example how i can handle the recursive calls if i omit the root_node parameter?

Comment: Since `root_node` is a local variable, updates to `root_node` are not reflected on `root`.

Comment: See http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html, the `Insert()` function, for one way to address the problem. There, the new root pointer is returned.